# Enlarging the width of a bitmap

Tags: android

I wrote acode that make the width of abitmap bigger but when i apply it,  the width get bigger but the size of the entire image get smaller,,  please help me this is my code :

```
public void max (View v){
 bmpnew = Bitmap.createBitmap( bmp1.getWidth()*3, bmp1.getHeight()*3, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  

bmpnew = bmpnew.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 ,true);

int a=0; /////x for bmp1
int b=0; /////y for bmp1
int h=0; /////x for bmpnew
int k=0; /////y for bmpnew


while (b<= hight-1){
    while( a<=width-1){
        int colorr= bmp1.getPixel(a, b);
        bmpnew.setPixel(h, k, colorr);
        bmpnew.setPixel(h+1, k, colorr);
        h+=2;
        a++;
    }
    b++;
    k++;
    a=0;
    h=0;
}   

iv.setImageBitmap(bmpnew);
```

Comment: @Henry Sorry i have edited it :) please help me

Answer (score 1):

Why to scale bitmap yourself? You can use [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29).

Comment: In my project I need to edit the size with this algorithm,, duplicating the pixels in each row to the next pixel beside it,, logically it shoud be bigger when i press max button, but why it become smaller